# Mysql Php Sum() Multiplication?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table. `t1` AND `t2`

Data as below `t1`, `kid` is planID, `uid` is Userid, `buytime` is buy quantity.

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| kid     | uid         | buytime1    | buytime2      |
+---------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1       | 1           | 10          | 5             |
| 1       | 2           | 1           | 0             |
| 1       | 3           | 3           | 5             |
| 2       | 4           | 1           | 10            |
| 3       | 5           | 20          | 6             |
+---------+-------------+-------------+---------------+
```

`t2` Data:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| ID      | costb1    | costb2    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1       | 100       | 200       |
| 2       | 300       | 500       |
| 3       | 1000      | 2000      |
+---------------------------------+
```

I would like to do the `SUM` in mysql like:

`SUM buytime1 * costb1 + buytime2 * costb2 Where t1.kid = t2.id`

```
$query = DB::query("SELECT SUM(something like buytime1 * costb1 + buytime2 * costb2) FROM ".DB::table('t1')." t1 LEFT JOIN ".DB::table('t2')." t2 ON (t1.kid = t2.id)");
```

so the final result should be `40700`

```
10 * 100 + 5 * 200 = 2000
1 * 100 + 0 * 200 = 100
3 * 100 + 5 * 200 = 1300
1 * 300 + 10 * 500 = 5300
20 * 1000 + 6 * 2000 = 32000
```

So what should i edit my coding in the `query`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `sum` as you provided -- this will result in 40700:

```
select sum((t1.buytime1 * t2.costb1) + (t1.buytime2 * t2.costb2))
from t1 
  join t2 on t1.kid = t2.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7feb87/1)

Not sure if you need the `outer join` - if so, then you need to define what those missing values should equal.  Using `coalesce` though should help there if needed.